# How to integrate gzip compression in php site?

Tags: php, gzip

Want to integrate gzip compression on my php site , but while I am implementing the code ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); it's giving me an error 'This webpage is not available' although the page exist in the server ,  gzip compression is also enabled in the server. Please suggest a way to implement it.

Comment: you might want to look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709076/how-to-enable-gzip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Hope it'll help you

at the top of your index page put it

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

And you need to do little more. Just write down below in your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css          application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>
```