# What to do if mod_expires and mod_gzip not present on hosting provider?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, mod-expires

What to do if mod_expires and mod_gzip not present on hosting provider?
My web hosting service doesnt have mod_expires and mod_gzip  active.
Is there any other way to compress and add expire headers to files using PHP or .HTACCESS?

We are using PHP 5.5.12 
Thanks

Comment: Find a better hosting provider. Alternatively you can add expires headers with `header()` but that doesn't work unless you serve everything with PHP. You can compress PHP's output with [ob_gzhandler](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

Comment: Kinda a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709076/how-to-enable-gzip