# compress csv before export in php

Tags: php, csv

Here is my code. Its working properly and now i want to compress the csv file before generate. Anybody please suggest me what to do!

```
$filename = 'Product_Export_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.csv';
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
// clean the output buffer
ob_clean();
echo trim($_SESSION['cProductCSVdata']);
$_SESSION['cProductCSVdata'] = '';
exit;
```

Comment: turn on gzip compression in your webserver. done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable gzip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709076/how-to-enable-gzip)

Answer (score 1):

Sending it to a zip file with ZipArchive is your solution. 
Here is an example with .txt files.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/too.php","/testfromfile.php");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
?>
```