# Why is ob_gzhandler not working?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.6

I use "**ob_gzhandler**" function for compressing contents. this is my codes:

```
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>This should be a compressed page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

don't throw any errors, but compressing operation not working!
in "**inspect element**" isn't **"content-encoding : gzip"** phrase!

[image]

my system information :

> Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 - Port defined for Apache: 80

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Php documentation says, that [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-gzhandler.php) requires `zlib`extension  to be installed, so make sure it is true:

```
 if (extension_loaded('zlib')){
    echo "zlib installed";
}
```

If it's installed, you can use `ob_gzhandler` and content will be compressed. The problem is you don't see **HTTP header** `Content-Encoding: gzip` in response headers. This header is not set by your web server, but you can set it from php, by means of [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
```

So, combining these two step you have a solution:

```
if (extension_loaded('zlib') && !ini_get('zlib.output_compression')){
    header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
}
```

I also check `.ini`configuration. If `zlib.output_compression` is `On`, **all output** will be compressed, so `ob_gzhandler` is redundant.

This code is valid, but it's not what php sould be used for. Compressing output and setting headers is **web server** responsibility. Please, read relevant answer, about [configuring .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709107/7804082), so Apache will do a compression and set correct response headers for you.

Comment: Please more description, i don't understand yet! Tnx

Comment: @Farshad, I've added some more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've followed all of the above, but the problem isn't solve ! please help me. tnx

Answer (score 2):

**Gotcha 1**

`ob_start(ob_gzhandler)` needs zero preoutput.

(Assert `<?` is the **very first byte** of your file.)

---

**Gotcha 2**

`ob_start(ob_gzhandler)` needs `zlib.output_compression_level` be between -1 and 9.

Comment: I've followed all of the above, but the problem isn't solve ! please help me. tnx

Comment: This answer makes literally zero sense. `ob_start(ob_gzhandler)` is the first thing called by PHP and thus would be the first thing output so how could someone possible "fix" this? It's also completely unclear what you are asserting is "wrong" with the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that *PHP* is correctly configured (no restart of any kind required); verified with PHP 7.3.10:

**php.ini**

```
zlib.output_compression = On

zlib.output_compression_level = 9
```

Secondly there are some weird bits. Don't try to manually set the `Content-Encoding` header, for some reason that seems to break pages. This code *must* start before *any* output (including spaces/tabs) is sent to the client:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'gzip'))
{
 ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
 //header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
}
```

Lastly you must ensure to properly handle "closing" the compression - *if* it is active:

```
if (ob_get_level() > 0) {ob_end_flush();}
```

I tried all of the above and had to change the last ending bit, hopefully this will save someone's sanity.